# Cannot connect to Imap server using Apache james from java code

Tags: java, imap, james

Can someone please provide a solution to the problem in

[How to connect to MailServer using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630969/how-to-connect-to-mailserver-using-javamail?s=3359cc91-fc84-4b23-92b0-69f5fe0fd2e1#new-answer)

I am stuck at the same point.

Comment: User never answered the questions.  Please provide a question, source, responses, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hupa is the web-mail in the james project, it uses javaMail to retrieve messages from imap servers. You can take some code to connect with your server from the [InMemoryIMAPStoreCache.java](https://github.com/apache/james-hupa/blob/trunk/server/src/main/java/org/apache/hupa/server/InMemoryIMAPStoreCache.java).